# Can Modbus slave report events to master?

Tags: modbus

I want to daisy chain Modbus slave with momentary switch.

Since Modbus is a Master/Slave protocole I’m not even sure if this is the way to go.

My understanding is that for the master to be aware of such events he must poll each single slave to read they register state.

Maybe this is trivial for this protocole and doesn’t generate overhang on the bus, or maybe I must switch to a different protocole?

I’ve found countless example of modbus master controlling slave (like motor, relay any kind of actuator) or even read temperature / humidity from sensors but I’m struggling to find any example of “events based sensors” Like momentary switch for instance...

Answer (score 1):

No, only the master can send data requests and also in Modbus RTU (serial) there can only exist a single master in the entire network.

With Modbus TCP there can be several masters.

If you want a protocol in which all connected devices can both send and read data take a look at **MQTT**, which works through the Publish-Subscribe system and not with Request-Response which is how most industrial protocols work, including Modbus.

Another protocol that could work for you is **OPC UA**, which apart from Request -Response also allows the master. through subscriptions. to receive data from a slave when the data value changes, without the need of a previous request.

Comment: The downside of MQTT is that it’s a TCP/IP based protocole I’m a right? I wanted to use a daisy chain topology for the wiring so I don’t need to run cat5 on every single wall switch

Comment: Yes, both MQTT and OPC UA work over and IP network, in the same way as all the latest protocols work. I don't think there is anything similar based on serial communication, less and less used

Comment: Take a look also at **CAN bus**